# Подскажите пожалуйста API или алгоритм анализа звука для отличия аппаратного шума от голоса или других "полезных" аудио данных

Tags: c++, аудио, анализ-данных

Задача переводить голос в текст не стоит - нужно лишь понимать когда у пользователя аппаратно выключен микрофон, то есть само устройство присутствует, но, например, нажат "mute" на гарнитуре. Так как гарнитуры бывают разного качества, на одной может быть тишина при mute, а на другой весьма громкий аппаратный шум, поэтому банальный анализ амплитуды сигнала будет давать недопустимые погрешности.

Есть ли алгоритмы или специальные библиотеки для подобной задачи?
Есть ли подобные средства в библиотеке PortAudio, с помощью которой и ведётся захват с микрофона (ну вдруг, чтобы лишнее не подключать)?

Comment: быстрое преобразование фурье и анализ спектра. Если на спектре будут отчетливые пики в области голосовых частот (100-400Гц) то значит голос есть, если спектр равномерный по всей полосе частот - скорее всего шум, через спектральный анализ можно отследить довольно много. Для более качественного определения речи и преобразования речь-текст уже необходимы будут фильтры и иные методы обработки звука. Для преобразований есть http://www.fftw.org/